# How to create nested tables in excel using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel, epplus

How can I create Nested tables using EPPlus (One cell contains another table) , is it possible ?

What I've tried :

1. Create nested `DataTable` (`DataTable` contains `DataColumn` of type `DataTable`) and bind it using `LoadFromDataTable` method . But it didn't work.
2. Create two different `Worksheets` and add one inside cell of the other one !! -seems stupid- it also didn't work.

any ideas please.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a pivot table?

Comment: Can you do that directly in excel (without merging cells)?

Comment: @Nimesh actually it was just about merging cells

Comment: That's what I intended to ask. If it can be done in Excel then it should be possible via libraries like EPPlus too (till the extent it's been programmed to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

putting a table inside a cell is not supported by excel and it's not logical , what I did to workaround this is to do small visual work-around.

just merge the header of the cell containing the sub-table (to make it look like 1 cell) then draw the sub-table under this merged header.